# How to search in serialized content

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have two tables

Table 1 is:

```
id | item_id
---------------
1  | a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}
```

and the second table is:

```
tag_id | tag
------------
1      | c
2      | java
```

I have stored the id of table two in table 1 after serialize.  Now  I want to search the tag in table 1 by mysql `%like%` but the problem is that if I want to search the tag have id 1 or 2 in the item_id it will always find the result even if there is not 1 stored by me but this is stored by the serialize function. Now I want to know what should I do? And any better approach/method will also be appreciated!

Comment: for the sake of **Normalization**, change your `table`'s` structure

Comment: @diEcho thankyou but this mistake is only on the so ..i have make it correct

Comment: I am not talking about **SO** formatting. i m saying for the your MySQL table's structure. :)

Comment: @diEcho ya sir i new the normalization ,would you let me know ho to do this

Comment: Golden Rule : never ever store multiple value in any column ( comma separted values )

Comment: @diEcho   how should i store these value ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15272/discussion-between-diecho-and-mayank-swami)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serialized data is not suitable for searching.

It's better to improve your table structure:

1. Table tags is the same as yours.
2. Table items_tags with stucture:

   1. id - autoincrement field
   2. item_id - ID of item with tag
   3. tag_id - tag ID

With following structure it's much more easier to search items with tags.

**Added**

Mayankswami, example queries: For all items with specified tag: `SELECT item_id FROM items_tags WHERE tag_id=(TAG_ID)` For item's tags: `SELECT * FROM item_tags AS IT LEFT JOIN tags AS T ON T.id=IT.tag_id WHERE item_id=(ITEM_ID)`

Comment: ya sir, i do know the table structure now i make it made it correct

Comment: @diEcho  i want to search the that is there is tag_id is present in the item id but as told by the  darkfigher i want to search it also giving the same result

Comment: @Mayankswami, example queries: For all items with specified tag: `SELECT item_id FROM items_tags WHERE tag_id=(TAG_ID)` For item's tags: `SELECT * FROM item_tags AS IT LEFT JOIN tags AS T ON T.id=IT.tag_id WHERE item_id=(ITEM_ID)`

Comment: If you can't do anything else and have to use just a serialized data, you can use REGEXP command in your query!

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html